# How to filter for specific rows in data matrix for R, my filter requirement is slightly complex

Tags: r

I am working with RNA seq data with cell clusters as my first column and gene expression as the top row. I want to compare rows 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, etc. for a specific column to see if there is two fold levels of expression. Anything with two fold expression levels or high is kept and anything less would be filtered out. I want to look at data where there is a relative fold change in gene expression.

I have tried to run this code but I'm still getting errors

> ```
> GeneName    Cluster_1    Cluster_1   Cluster_2  Cluster_2 Cluster_3   Cluster_3
> Itga9       0.019        0.004       0.028        0.020      0.053      0.045
> Itga1       0.018        0.012       0.016        0.011      0.016       0.030
> Npnt        0.000        0.000       0.000        0.000      0.000       0.000
> Agrn        0.014        0.012       0.019        0.014      0.012       0.015
> Cd36        0.028        0.107       0.035        0.037      0.030       0.074
> Cd44        0.063        0.132       0.105        0.112      0.143       0.186
> Chad        0.000        0.000       0.000        0.000      0.000       0.000        
>
>
> My_Data <- My_Data[2:7,2:7] 
> My_Data <- t(My_Data) foo = function(x) { 
> if (length(x) %% 2 == 1) {
> stop("Odd number of rows!")  
> }  
>  odd = seq(1, length(x), by = 2) 
>  even = odd + 1   
>  ratio = x[odd] / x[even]  
>  return(any(ratio >= 2 |
>  ratio <= 0.5)) } FilteredDf <- Filter(foo, My_Data)
> ```

For some reason its producing the error:
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Odd number of rows!

Comment: You'll get the best answers if you post a reproducible example with your input and expected output and the code you tried so far. Plus, it's polite. You can post a sample of your data using the function `dput()`

Comment: So you are comparing rows 1 and 2. And 3 and 4. But not 2 and 3, correct?

Comment: Okay, so. You have an odd number of rows. You can see how the first line of my function checks is the number of rows are odd, and `stop`s (throwing an error) if this is the case. This is because your description and comments made it clear what to do with an even number of rows (compare 1 to 2; 3 to 4, 5 to 6, etc.). If there is an odd number of rows, what do you want to happen with the last row? Ignore it? something else? As I suggested in my answer - you might need to modify the function for whatever you want done in this case.

Comment: If you read through my answer and my code and understand it, you should be able to adapt it to do what you need (once you decide).

Comment: @Gregor But I don't have an odd amount of rows, As you can see from my df, its an even number. I have only 6 rows, which is why. I understood your code, I think it may have something to do with me renaming the row names to the gene names ?but I am not too sure.

Comment: @Gregor I just checked it still shows the same error

Comment: You have an odd number of rows. `Itga9` is 1. `Itga1` is 2. `Npnt` is 3. `Agrn` is 4. `Cd36` is 5. `Cd44` is 6. `Chad` is 7. That is your last row. 7 is odd. Please double check your assumptions.

Comment: @Gregor First of all thank you so much for your help thus far. 
I was thinking the line My_Data <- My_Data[2:7,2:7] made ithe number of rows even though? I am pretty sure the number of rows and columns are both even, I tried to troubleshoot already and every iteration with my code. I am sorry for the troubles I am really new to programming  as you can tell. So I honestly really appreciate you helping me.

Comment: The problem is that after you transpose `t(My_Data)` it's not longer a data frame---that converts it to a `matrix`. When `Filter` works on a matrix, it does it value-by-value, not column-by-column like a data frame. Convert it back to a data frame, `My_Data = as.data.frame(My_data)` before doing the `Filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that does your test on a single column and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, then use `Filter` to apply it to every column in the data frame and keep only the `TRUE`s:

```
foo = function(x) {
  if (length(x) %% 2 == 1) {
    stop("Odd number of rows!")
  }
  odd = seq(1, length(x), by = 2)
  even = odd + 1
  ratio = x[odd] / x[even]
  return(any(ratio >= 2 | ratio <= 0.5))
}
Filter(foo, my_df)
#       a
# 1 0.000
# 2 0.000
# 3 4.020
# 4 2.004
# 5 1.001
# 6 0.004
```

I'll leave it up to you to modify the function as you may need (e.g., if the input number of rows is odd).

Using this data:

```
my_df <- read.table(text ='          a      b     c
1         0.000  0.001 0.883
2         0.000  0.001 1.471
3         4.020  0.003 1.357
4         2.004  0.004 1.618
5         1.001  0.005 1.110
6         0.004  0.006 1.048', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I Will Add another comment below @Gregor

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is very vague. I'm not sure why you are transposing your data `t(My_Data)`? Instead of commenting, please update your question with data that doesn't work (since the data in your question does work). And also be more specific about "doesn't work" --- is there an error? A result that seems wrong (what's wrong about it?)? R crashes? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
require(dplyr)


my_df <- read.table(text ='a      b     c
         0.000  0.001 0.883
         0.000  0.001 1.471
         0.000  0.003 1.357
         10.004  0.004 1.618
         3.001  0.005 1.110
         0.004  0.006 1.048', header = TRUE)


## in the first step you will create a (duplicate) column tha shifts the rows upwards by 1

# the purpose is that you can apply functions horizontally 



my_df %>% 
  mutate(lead_a = lead(a)) %>%
  select(a, lead_a, b, c) %>%  
  head 


#       a lead_a     b     c
# 1  0.000  0.000 0.001 0.883
# 2  0.000  0.000 0.001 1.471
# 3  0.000 10.004 0.003 1.357
# 4 10.004  3.001 0.004 1.618
# 5  3.001  0.004 0.005 1.110
# 6  0.004     NA 0.006 1.048



# as you can see row 1 in lead_a is the same as row 2 in a !
# now you can compare row 1 to row2 3 to 4 etc...
```

Comment: My desired is Column a (I want to compare row 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6 Of the SAME column)

Comment: Yes, that's what the answer achieves, I edited for clarity.

Comment: I think you have two problems: (1) OP wants to compare rows 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, *but not* rows 2 and 3, 4 and 5. (2) OP wants the comparison done for *all* columns, and to keep all the columns that meet the requirement.